# Why does my jQuery hover function only works for one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-hover

I am trying to create a jquery function to change an image when I hover over the the image, it works for the first image but not for the second, I am not sure why.

**Buttons**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var imgLinkedIn = $('#imgLinkedIn');
  var imgGithub = $('#imgGithub');

  imgLinkedIn.hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","images/linkedIn-hover.png");
            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","images/linkedIn.png");
    });

  imgGithub.hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","images/Octocat-hover.png");
      }, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","images/Octocat.png");
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
      <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/pub/ife-a/27/273/745" title="LinkedIn" id="imgLinkedin"  target="_blank">
        <img class="imgContactLogos" id="imgLinkedIn" src="images/linkedIn.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://github.com/cinofr3t" title="Github" id="imgGithub" target="_blank">
        <img class="imgContactLogos" id="imgGithub" src="images/Octocat.png"/>
      </a>
```

Comment: Probably there is a problem in jquery selector for `imgGithub`. How `imgGithub` is defined in code?

Comment: what is imgLinkedIn and imgGithub?

Comment: or probably the second imgGithub is being appended to DOM after the event is attached.. Can we see you HTML code?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev i have updated the code to show how they are defined

Comment: Make sure the id is unique on the page

Comment: Do the images all have the same ID? That should be changed to a class and the selector would become `var imgLinkedIn = $('.imgLinkedIn');`. Provide more HTML markup and the issue would be more apparent.

Comment: You have the same `id` on both the links and the images. Why that causes one to work and the other not to I can't answer - but it's certainly related!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
 <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/pub/ife-a/27/273/745" title="LinkedIn"  target="_blank">
        <img class="imgContactLogos" id="imgLinkedIn" src="images/linkedIn.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://github.com/cinofr3t" title="Github" target="_blank">
        <img class="imgContactLogos" id="imgGithub" src="images/Octocat.png"/>
      </a>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#imgLinkedIn').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/linkedIn-hover.png");
}, function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/linkedIn.png");
});

$('#imgGithub').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/Octocat-hover.png");
}, function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/Octocat.png");
});
```

NOTE: This will works if both images are present in the DOM after page loads. If you are loading it dynamically then you have to use jQuery `.on` method.

Comment: I don't follow how this is any different from the original code?!?

Comment: I dont see how this is different

Comment: First 2 line you have not provided before!

Comment: Is these element are present on DOM or are you loading these dynamically?

Comment: You have updated you question after I answered. That's way it's same @ifelabolz

Comment: they are already present in the DOM, all i'm doing is assigning them to a new variable when my document is ready, ill update with everything on my page js for you to see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91756/discussion-between-deepak-biswal-and-ife-labolz).

Comment: Check with my codes now. I have updated some codes in HTML section.

Comment: Same id was exist for `a` and `img` tag. I have removed that from `a` tag.